# Responsive metro blocks within flexbox

Tags: css, layout, microsoft-metro, responsive-design, flexbox

how would you got about including metro look blocks within flexbox, to keep it all responsive?

This is what I have so far(html):

```
    `<div id='main22'>
     <middle22>Middle section with a picture</middle22>
     <left22>Left side (metro look blocks)</left22>
     <right22>Right side (metro look blocks)</right22>
     </div>`
```

Then this would be the css part:

```
    `#main22 {
     min-height: auto;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display:         flex;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row;
       flex-flow: row;
     }

     #main22 > middle22 {
     margin: 2px;
     padding: 3px;
     background: #aaaaaa;
     -webkit-flex: 3 1 30%;
       flex: 3 1 30%;
     -webkit-order: 2;
       order: 2;
     }

     #main22 > left22 {
     margin: 2px;
     padding: 3px;
     background: #bbbbbb;
     -webkit-flex: 1 6 30%;
       flex: 1 6 30%;
     -webkit-order: 1;
       order: 1;
     }

     #main22 > right22 {
     margin: 2px;
     padding: 3px;

     background: #cccccc;
     -webkit-flex: 1 6 30%;
       flex: 1 6 30%;
     -webkit-order: 3;
       order: 3;
     }

     @media all and (max-width: 640px) {

     #main22 {
     -webkit-flex-flow: column;
        flex-flow: column;
      }

     #main22 > middle22, #main22 > left22, #main22 > right22 {
     -webkit-order: 0;
        order: 0;
     }

     #main22 > left22, #main22 > right22 {
     min-height: 50px;
     max-height: auto;
     }
     }`
```

So far it works great on all devices, the middle section should be in the middle on desktops and bigger tablets and on top when on smartphones. I would like to have a image inside it (centered). In the left and right section I would like to have 4 metro look buttons (2 on the left, 2 on the right) with icon in the middle and title in the left bottom corner, just as it is in the windows 8 metro look

How would you go from here to make those metro look blocks?

Comment: What have you tried?  It's helpful to include a demo as well:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/kmvsuzgx